Attempting to change into 32-bit protected mode causes triple fault
I have a simplistic bootloader comprised of two parts - the actual bootloader that loads the second 'stage' into memory, and executes it.
In that second stage, I'm trying to switch to 32-bit protected mode, but I end up with a triple-fault, with the following error in bochs:

Below is the code for both boot assembly files, as well as the Makefile that I am compiling them with, in case there's some error there.
From what I can tell, there seems to be some issue with the descriptors in the GDT, but I've checked them multiple times and they seem to be correct. I wonder if it's something to do with loading the code into memory at a different address than expected maybe? I'm unsure. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!
Makefile
BUILD_DIR?=build
FLOPPY_OUTPUT?=$(BUILD_DIR)/floppy.img

.PHONY: all bootloader kernel run-bochs run-qemu build-dir

all: $(FLOPPY_OUTPUT)

run-bochs: all
    bochs -f bochsrc.txt

run-qemu: all
    qemu-system-i386 -monitor stdio -drive file=$(FLOPPY_OUTPUT),format=raw

# TODO: Make the drive a hard drive with FAT32.
$(FLOPPY_OUTPUT): build-dir bootloader kernel
    dd if=/dev/zero of=$(FLOPPY_OUTPUT) bs=512 count=2880
    mkfs.fat -F12 -n "AURORAOS" $(FLOPPY_OUTPUT)
    dd if=$(BUILD_DIR)/boot.bin of=$(FLOPPY_OUTPUT) conv=notrunc
    mcopy -i $(FLOPPY_OUTPUT) build/lstage.bin "::lstage.bin"

bootloader: build-dir bootloader/boot.asm bootloader/late_stage/lstage.asm
    nasm -f bin bootloader/boot.asm -o $(BUILD_DIR)/boot.bin
    nasm -felf bootloader/late_stage/lstage.asm -o $(BUILD_DIR)/lstage.o
    ld -melf_i386 -T bootloader/late_stage/linker.ld $(BUILD_DIR)/lstage.o -o $(BUILD_DIR)/lstage.bin --oformat=binary

kernel:

build-dir:
    mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)

linker.ld
ENTRY(_start)

SECTIONS
{
    . = 0x0000;
    .text : {
       *(.text) 
    }

    .rodata : {
       *(.rodata) 
    }

    .data : {
       *(.data) 
    }

    .bss : {
       *(.bss) 
    }
}

lstage.asm - Where the triple fault occurs:
[bits 16]

global _start
_start:
    mov si, msg_hello
    call puts

    cli

    call enable_a20
    call load_gdt

    mov eax, cr0
    or eax, 1
    mov cr0, eax

    jmp dword CODE_SEGMENT:pmode_start

puts:
.loop:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz .done
    mov ah, 0x0E
    int 0x10
    jmp .loop
.done:
    ret

enable_a20:
    ; DataPort = 60
    ; CommandPort = 64
    ; DisableKeyboard = AD
    ; EnableKeyboard = AE
    ; ReadCtrl = D0
    ; WriteCtrl = D1

    call a20_wait_input
    mov al, 0xAD ; Disable keyboard
    out 0x64, al

    call a20_wait_input
    mov al, 0xD0 ; Read control output port
    out 0x64, al

    call a20_wait_output
    in al, 0x60
    push eax

    call a20_wait_input
    mov al, 0xD1
    out 0x64, al

    call a20_wait_input
    pop eax
    or al, 2
    out 0x60, al

    call a20_wait_input
    mov al, 0xAE ; Enable keyboard
    out 0x64, al

    call a20_wait_input
    ret


a20_wait_input:
    push ax
    in al, 0x64
    test al, 2
    jnz a20_wait_input
    pop ax
    ret

a20_wait_output:
    push ax
    in al, 0x64
    test al, 1
    jz a20_wait_output
    pop ax
    ret

load_gdt:
    lgdt [gdt_descriptor]

    ret

gdt_start:
null_descriptor: dq 0
code_descriptor: dw 0xFFFF ; Limit (0-15)
                 dw 0x0000 ; Base (0-15)
                 db 0x0   ; Base (16-23)
                 db 10011010b ; Access
                 db 11001111b ; Flags + Limit (16-19)
                 db 0x0 ; Base (24-31)
data_descriptor: dw 0xFFFF ; Limit (0-15)
                 dw 0x0000 ; Base (0-15)
                 db 0x0   ; Base (16-23)
                 db 10010010b ; Access
                 db 11001111b ; Flags + Limit (16-19)
                 db 0x0 ; Base (24-31)
gdt_end:

gdt_descriptor: dw gdt_descriptor - gdt_start - 1
                dd gdt_start

CODE_SEGMENT equ code_descriptor - gdt_start
DATA_SEGMENT equ data_descriptor - gdt_start

msg_hello: db "Hello from late-stage boot code!", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00

[bits 32]
pmode_start:
    cli
    hlt

boot.asm - The actual bootloader that loads lstage.bin into memory.
[org 0x7C00]
[bits 16]

jmp strict short _start
nop

oem_identifier: db "MSWIN4.1"
bytes_per_sector: dw 0x0200 ; 512
sectors_per_cluster: db 0x01
reserved_sectors: dw 0x0001 
fat_count: db 0x02
root_dir_entries: dw 0x00E0
total_sectors: dw 0x0B40 ; 2880 * 512 = 1.44MB
media_descriptor_type: db 0xF0 ; 3.5" floppy
sectors_per_fat: dw 0x0009
sectors_per_track: dw 0x0012 ; 18
head_count: dw 0x0002 
hidden_sectors: dd 0x0000 0000
large_sector_count: dd 0x0000 0000

; Extended Boot Partition
drive_number: db 0x00 ; 0x00 = floppy, 0x80 = hard disk
_reserved: db 0x00
signature: db 0x29
serial_number: dd 0x12345678 ; Unused
volume_label: db "AURORAOS   "
system_ident_string: db "FAT12   "

_start:
    mov ax, 0
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 0x7C00

    mov [drive_number], dl 

    ; 07C0:0000 -> 0000:07C0
    push es
    push word .after
    retf
.after:

    mov si, msg_hello
    call puts

    ; Read drive params rather than relying on hard-coded values
    ; INT 13/AH=08h -> http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0621.htm
    push es
    mov ah, 0x08
    int 0x13
    jc floppy_error
    pop es

    ; CH = low eight bits of max cylinder
    ; CL [bits 7-6] = high two bits of max cylinder
    ; CL [bits 5-0] = max sector number 
    ; DH = max head number
    ; DL = number of drives

    and cl, 0x3F
    xor ch, ch
    ; Now, cx is just sector count, as we removed bits [7-0]
    mov [sectors_per_track], cx

    ; Heads are indexed from 0, so max head number
    ; is one less than the count of heads.
    inc dh
    mov [head_count], dh

    ; Compute LBA of root dir = reserved + fats * sectors per fat
    mov ax, [sectors_per_fat]
    mov bl, [fat_count]
    xor bh, bh
    mul bx
    add ax, [reserved_sectors]
    push ax ; LBA

    ; Compute sector size of root dir = (32 * number of entries) / bytes_per_sector
    mov ax, [root_dir_entries]
    shl ax, 5
    xor dx, dx
    div word [bytes_per_sector]

    test dx, dx
    jz .root_dir_size_no_inc
    inc ax ; % bytes_per_sector > 0 => we need to round up
.root_dir_size_no_inc:

    mov cl, al ; cl = # of sectors to read
    pop ax ; LBA
    mov dl, [drive_number]
    mov bx, buffer
    call disk_read

    ; Search for LSTAGE BIN
    xor bx, bx
    mov di, buffer

.search_lstage:
    mov si, file_lstage_bin
    mov cx, 11 ; 11 bytes
    push di
    repe cmpsb
    pop di
    je .found_lstage

    add di, 32
    inc bx
    cmp bx, [root_dir_entries]
    jl .search_lstage
    jmp lstage_not_found_error

.found_lstage:

    ; di has address to the entry
    mov ax, [di + 26] ; First logical cluster field at offset 26
    mov [lstage_cluster], ax

    ; Load first FAT into memory
    mov ax, [reserved_sectors]
    mov bx, buffer
    mov cl, [sectors_per_fat]
    mov dl, [drive_number]
    call disk_read

    mov bx, LSTAGE_LOAD_SEGMENT
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, LSTAGE_LOAD_OFFSET

.load_lstage_loop:
    mov ax, [lstage_cluster]

    ; TODO: unhardcode this
    add ax, 31 ; ((lstage_cluster - 2) * sectors_per_cluster) + reserved + fats + root_dir_size

    mov cl, 1
    mov dl, [drive_number]
    call disk_read

    add bx, [bytes_per_sector]

    mov ax, [lstage_cluster]
    mov cx, 3
    mul cx
    mov cx, 2
    div cx ; ax = index of entry in FAT, dx = cluster % 2

    mov si, buffer
    add si, ax
    mov ax, [ds:si] ; read entry from FAT table at index ax

    or dx, dx
    jz .even

    ; Align and get 12 bits (1.5 bytes)
.odd:
    shr ax, 4
    jmp .next_cluster_after
.even:
    and ax, 0x0FFF

.next_cluster_after:
    cmp ax, 0x0FF8 ; end of chain
    jge .read_finish

    mov [lstage_cluster], ax
    jmp .load_lstage_loop

.read_finish:
    mov dl, [drive_number]

    mov ax, LSTAGE_LOAD_SEGMENT
    mov ds, ax
    mov es, ax

    jmp LSTAGE_LOAD_SEGMENT:LSTAGE_LOAD_OFFSET

    jmp halt

halt:
    cli
    hlt
    jmp halt

lstage_not_found_error:
    mov si, msg_lstage_not_found
    call puts
    jmp halt

floppy_error:
    mov si, msg_floppy_error
    call puts
    jmp halt

;
; Convert LBA to CHS
;
; Parameters:
;   - ax: LBA
; Returns:
;   - cx [bits 0-5]: sector number
;   - cx [bits 6-15]: cylinder
;   - dh: head
;
lba_to_chs:
    push ax
    push dx

    xor dx, dx                          ; dx = 0
    div word [sectors_per_track]        ; ax = LBA / sectors_per_track
                                        ; dx = LBA % sectors_per_track

    inc dx                              ; dx = sector
    mov cx, dx

    xor dx, dx
    div word [head_count]               ; ax = (LBA / sectors_per_track) / heads = cylinder
                                        ; dx = (LBA / sectors_per_track) % heads = head

    mov dh, dl                          ; dh = head
    mov ch, al                          ; cylinder [15-8]
    shl ah, 6
    or cl, ah                           ; last 2 bits

    pop ax
    mov dl, al
    pop ax
    ret

;
; Read sectors from disk
;
; Parameters:
;   - ax: LBA
;   - cl: number of sectors to read
;   - dl: drive number
;   - es:bx: buffer
;
disk_read:
    pusha
    
    push cx
    call lba_to_chs
    pop ax                  ; al = sectors to read

    mov ah, 0x02
    mov di, 0x05            ; retry count

.retry:
    pusha
    stc
    int 0x13
    jnc .done

    popa
    call disk_reset

    dec di
    test di, di
    jnz .retry
.fail:
    jmp floppy_error
.done:
    popa
    popa
    ret

;
; Reset disk controller
;
; Parameters:
;   - dl: drive number
;
disk_reset:
    pusha
    mov ah, 0x00
    stc
    int 0x03
    jc floppy_error
    popa
    ret

puts:
    pusha
.loop:
    lodsb
    or al, al
    jz .done
    mov ah, 0x0E
    int 0x10
    jmp .loop
.done:
    popa
    ret

msg_hello: db "Hello, world!", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00
msg_floppy_error: db "Read error.", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00
msg_lstage_not_found: db "LSTAGE.BIN not found.", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x00

lstage_cluster: dw 0x0000
LSTAGE_LOAD_SEGMENT equ 0x2000
LSTAGE_LOAD_OFFSET equ 0x0000

file_lstage_bin: db "LSTAGE  BIN"

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0AA55h

buffer:


Check if your gdt_descriptor actually contains what you want it to be. I don't think dd gdt_start would produce proper 32-bit linear address for GDT table. Also you might want to force 32-bit addressing (fword modifierforlgdt` and pm mode jump.
